# How to deploy an on-premises gateway service using service principal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, gateway

I'm using an on-premises gateway connection in Azure and I'm trying to deploy this using an ARM-template from a VSTS deployment. The VSTS deployment has an Resource Manager end-point. It seems that the service principal cannot create the On-premises Data Gateway service in Azure because it has no permission to the registered Gateway that is located in:

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/{location}/connectionGatewayInstallations/{OnPremGatewayId}
```

The code in the ARM template is quite straigtforward and looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways",
  "name": "[variables('OnPremGatewayName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "scale": null,
  "properties": {
    "connectionGatewayInstallation": {
      "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionid, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', toLower(replace(resourceGroup().location,' ','')),'/connectionGatewayInstallations/', parameters('OnPremGatewayId'))]"
    }
  },
  "dependsOn": []
},
```

The deployment throws this error:

```
"error": {
"code": "AuthorizationFailed",
"message": "The connection gateway 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx' does not exist or the client with object id 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx' under tenant id '********' does not have administrative rights on it."
}
}'
```

I've found that there is a new action added that you can assign to a role:

```
/Microsoft.Web/Locations/connectiongatewayinstallations/Read
```

I've created a role with this action and added it to the service principal, but dat didn't seem to help. I used the following script to create the role:

```
$role = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition "Virtual Machine Contributor"
$role.Id = $null
$role.Name = "On premises data gateway reader"
$role.Description = "Read registered On premises data gateways"
$role.Actions.Clear()
$role.Actions.Add("/Microsoft.Web/Locations/connectiongatewayinstallations/Read")
$role.AssignableScopes.Clear()
$role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}")
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Role $role
Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Name "On premises data gateway reader"
```

How can I give the VSTS service principal administrative rights on the registered gateway?

Comment: well, i assume you would need something more than read to actually edit properties of an object

Comment: Do you use private agent of vsts? What's the result if you deploy the ARM template manually? And what's the detail code of ARM template?

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the detail log on the OneDrive (remove personal information)

Comment: We use a hosted vs2017 agent in visualstudio.com.
If I run the ARM deployment locally and I'm logged in with the account that I installed the local gateway with, the deployment succeeds. If I try locally and I log in the service principal that is used for deployment from vsts, it fails.
I've added the part of the ARM template that takes care of the gateway deployment.

Comment: What's the result if you try it with private agent on your machine?

Comment: I've already created a service request for this issue. I'll give an update of the results here.

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: The last update was that they started a discussion, and this is not possible right now. I've sent an more detailed desciption of my usage scenario.
When I run the ARM template from my own computer using my own credentials that I used to install the Gateway application with, it's possible to run the ARM deployment. If I run it with the VSTS service principal, I get the error. So I guess for this deploment to work, we would need to give the VSTS service principal some sort of access to the registered gateway, but this is not possible right now.